# CSS - overflow-y: hidden doesn't work in safari

Tags: css, html

I would like hidden the scrollbar in the select options elements. In Chrome is working fine but in Safari not.

Chrome:

[image]

Safari:

[image]

I have been reading about this and in the Mozzila documentation says that is compatible to Safari:

https://developer.mozilla.org/ca/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-y

The code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>Test</title>

    <style>
              select{
                overflow-y: hidden;

              }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <div class='container'>

        <select size='2'>

          <option>This is a test</option>
          <option>This is a test 2</option>

        </select>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Do you know what is happen?

Answer (score 0):

Try to inline your css by saying

```
 <select size='2' style="overflow-y: hidden">
      <option>This is a test</option>
      <option>This is a test 2</option>
 </select>
```

Comment: It's the same that put in the head between <style> tag.

Answer (score 0):

There are curiosities in how browsers implement `overflow` properties. The standard workaround at the moment is to command

```
overflow: hidden;
overflow-x: visible;
```

Since it seems that this won't work on Safari, you must resort to a hackish workaround, CSS that matches the scrollbar itself:

```
<style>
    select::-webkit-scrollbar{ width:1px; background-color:transparent }
</style>
```

Comment: I set the same result. The scrollbar doesn't hidden in safari browser.

Comment: You are right. There is a workaround though, I'll edit my answer.